# Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation

Tags: thingsboard

I installed thingsboard on Ubuntu 18.04 based on "https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=kafka" tutorial. When I run installation script I face "Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.thingsboard.server.dao.exception.DataValidationException: User with email 'sysadmin@thingsboard.org'  already present in database!". Pls someone help me.

Comment: In which step do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the database already has an admin user.

I assume, that this is the command that is failing:

```
# --loadDemo option will load demo data: users, devices, assets, rules, widgets.
sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo
```

This script will setup the database tables and create the admin user (and load demo-data optionally).
When you run this script twice against the same database you recieve your error message, because the database already has its admin user.

So you should be able to fix this by either

- clearing/droping/recreating the database to run the installation script again
  or
- not calling the installation script twice at all